# Double centralizer properties

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and $M$ a right $A$-module. Then $M$ is a left $B=End_A(M)$-module.
$M$ is said to have the double centralizer property in case the canonical map given by right multiplication $F: A \rightarrow End_{B^{op}}(M)^{op}$ is an isomorphism (of algebras). That $F$ is injective means that $M$ is faithful as an $A$-module, meaning $Ma \neq 0$ for all nonzero $a \in A$.
The most famous situation is when $M=fA$ for some idempotent $f$, such that $fA$ is minimal faithful projective-injective. Examples include Schur algebras and blocks of category $\mathcal{O}$.
Questions: 
Let $M=fA$ for some idempotent $f$ (and add some properties if needed, such as M being injective or...)

- Is there an example where the two algebras $A$ and $End_{B^{op}}(M)^{op}$ are isomorphic as algebras but there is no double centralizer property?
  (answer is no,see comments in the answer)
- Is there an example where the two algebras $A$ and $End_{B^{op}}(M)^{op}$ have the same dimension as a vector-space but there is no double centralizer property? (Answer is yes: see the answer by Dag Oskar Madsen.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example for the second question: Let $A$ be the $4$-dimensional algebra $$A=\begin{pmatrix} \Bbbk & 0\\ \Bbbk & \Bbbk \end{pmatrix} \times \Bbbk$$ and $$f=(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},0)$$ Then $B={\rm{End}}_A(fA) \cong \Bbbk$ and $${\rm{End}}_{B^{\rm{op}}}(fA)^{\rm{op}}={\rm{End}}_{\Bbbk}(\Bbbk^2) \cong M_2(\Bbbk),$$ which is also $4$-dimensional but not isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: Thanks, do you also have a counterexample when assuming that A is connected?

Comment: Yes. Use the same idea with $A=\begin{pmatrix} \Bbbk[x]/(x^2) & 0\\ (x)/(x^2)& \Bbbk \end{pmatrix}$, which is also $4$-dimensional. Then $fA$ is not longer injective though.

Comment: In the article "morita theory, revisited" by kerner and yamgata, lemma 2.1. says that the double centraliser property holds in case there is an algebra isomorphism. thus your post answers all remaining questions.